# PHP Cron Page Not Working

Tags: php, apache, cron

I have an Apache server that I'm hosting from.

I have a php page that sends emails based on some script that looks like this:

```
 <?php
 chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); //need this line so cron works! cron doesn't know 
 the relative file paths otherwise.
 require_once 'core/init.php';
 $db = DB::getInstance();

 $company = new Company(1);

 require 'added-assets/plugins/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer;

 if($company->find_yesterday_appts(1)) { 
 .... email based on query....
```

From cpanel I have the cron job set to run every day at 12.

```
 0  12  *   *   *   php -q public_html/personnellonline/email_yesterdays_appts.php
```

core/init.php contains my connection string.

There are no errors I was told on the server, but no emails are ever sent when the cron runs.   If I go to the page directly though then the query runs and emails are sent!

I once solved this issue by adding:

```
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); //need this line so cron works! cron doesn't 
 know the relative file paths otherwise.
```

But not I'm back to square one.  Any thoughts on what could be the issue?

Comment: Nobody can remotely test for errors. Have you tried running it on the CLI?

Comment: `the relative file paths otherwise.` is this on a new like in the question. or is it actually a comment in the real code.  Because the way you have it in the question is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I go to the page directly", how exactly are you getting things to work?  Does running the PHP command you showed us work without using cron?

If you are loading the page through a web server, that is not the same as executing the file through PHP as you are doing in your cron command.  If your script needs to be run through the web server, try using curl to load the URL that works in your cron command.

The only other thing I could think of, if running the PHP command actually works when not run through cron, would be that you may need a specific user to execute your cron command.

Comment: "I go to the page directly" does mean that if I just type the php page into my brower and hit enter, the php page runs properly and emails are sent.  

I'll have to look into your other suggestions.   Haven't tried CLI. Never done that before, so that's a new thing for me.

Comment: Cron jobs shouldn't be accessible from the webroot, ideally.

Comment: If you have not tried the CLI, then why use it for your cron command?  If you use `curl` you can hit the web site just like if you were using your browser.

Answer (score 0):

GracefulRestart, I changed the command to use CURL which I never used or heard of.  It works now, thank you. I'm learning about CURL now as I read online.

ArtisticPhoenix, you are correct. I should move this outside the public area of my domain. I will do this!

The following works now:

```
 curl -s "https://www.example.com/email_yesterdays_appts.php"
```

Thank you for your comments and help.